# Pandas resample with all day range

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data like this:

```
2013-10-01 11:11:22, 12
2013-10-01 11:15:22, 12
2013-10-01 15:11:22, 12
2013-10-01 16:11:22, 12
2013-10-01 16:45:22, 12
```

I use code below to resample data:

```
df.resample('1H', how=lambda x: len(x))
```

The result will be like this:

```
2013-10-01 11:00:00, 2
2013-10-01 12:00:00, 0
2013-10-01 13:00:00, 0
2013-10-01 14:00:00, 0
2013-10-01 15:00:00, 1
2013-10-01 16:00:00, 2
```

But I want the whole day range from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00, how can I change the resample date range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you ccan `reindex` after the resample using a hourly period index for the whole day. So something like the following:

```
>>> rng = pd.period_range('2013-10-01',periods=24, freq='H').to_timestamp()
>>> df.resample('1H', how=lambda x: len(x)).reindex(index=rng,fill_value=0)

                     value
2013-10-01 00:00:00      0
2013-10-01 01:00:00      0
2013-10-01 02:00:00      0
2013-10-01 03:00:00      0
2013-10-01 04:00:00      0
2013-10-01 05:00:00      0
2013-10-01 06:00:00      0
2013-10-01 07:00:00      0
2013-10-01 08:00:00      0
2013-10-01 09:00:00      0
2013-10-01 10:00:00      0
2013-10-01 11:00:00      2
2013-10-01 12:00:00      0
2013-10-01 13:00:00      0
2013-10-01 14:00:00      0
2013-10-01 15:00:00      1
2013-10-01 16:00:00      2
2013-10-01 17:00:00      0
2013-10-01 18:00:00      0
2013-10-01 19:00:00      0
2013-10-01 20:00:00      0
2013-10-01 21:00:00      0
2013-10-01 22:00:00      0
2013-10-01 23:00:00      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert your date to datetime format with `from datetime import datetime` and then use `pd.Series(datetime.strptime...)`. Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html then you can manipulate your data easier.

Comment: It is DateTime or I can not resample it.